# Use boost convex hull on spatial graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph, geometry

If there's boost graph that has position data embedded in its vertices (which are floats), is there a way to use the [boost convex hull algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/convex_hull.html), and get the vertices as the output.

The graph is defined as so:

```
    struct RoadVertexData {
     long long id;
     glm::vec3 position;
    };

using RGraph = boost::adjacency_list < boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, RoadVertexData>;
```

You can convert it to/from points to vertices with some effort, but I'm trying to understand whether it can be done without this effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done without the effort.

You can however optimize for runtime cost by trading in for development cost.

> Note that this will be development cost now, for testing and whenever you need to change your datastructure in the future. Nothing new, this is how decoupling software always works and worked.
>
> Increasing coupling in the name of optimization brings the cost of added coupling.

Now, the work to do is not trivial. You will have to adapt the graph type as the geometry concept you want it to model.

- [Concepts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts.html)
- The [existing adaptations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted.html) can serve as building blocks/examples

How you will get your results back is another question. I'm assuming you would expect that to be a graph? Or just a sequence of vertex descriptors? The latter is obviously simpler.

### The Other Way Around?

If your graph represent a mainly geometric concept, consider going the reverse route. Boost Graph also lists the requirements for its [Graph Concepts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html) so you might want to store your data as a Boost Geometry data structure and adapt that.

Comment: I was thinking there was a templated method/class or callback that I could extend, say that in my data structure the points coordinates are located here, and use that as you iterate through the points.